# How to access iOS receipt fields/attributes without validating the receipt?

Tags: ios, receipt-validation

Is it possible to access the receipt fields and information without running any validation at all?

I found several tutorials which put a lot of effort in getting the correct certificate, running the validation, etc. **I do not need the validation** but only want to access the some receipt fields (e.g. `Original Application Version`) without too much trouble (If anyone tries to hack the app and use it for free, so be it).

I understand that OpenSSL **can** be used to decode and validate the receipt but itn't there an easier way to do this if validation is not required?

Answer (score 1):

No, the validation is tied up with decrypting the receipt. You can't get at the fields without unpacking the receipt which requires OpenSSL or something like it. If you don't care about people cracking your app and bypassing In App purchases then just use one of the receipt libraries. Here's one from Black Pixel called [IAPKit](https://github.com/blackpixel/IAPKit)